# What are some places to get good reference material?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, image

I want a few sites to get good reference images of objects, machines, humans. Anything. I want to model objects more precisely, but in the end, I always end up using my creativity since I don't find good reference material on objects

Comment: Do you know any place like the-blueprints.com? Sites like it are what I'm looking for

Comment: Hello :). Better furniture brands like Knoll, Fredericia often include blueprints in their catalogues. They want to get their products featured in archviz scenes :))

Comment: And to add - the linked thread already contains a "Blueprints" category :)